# Convert hotkeys only when certain window is active

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use `ifWinActive` in order to achieve this:
When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and MLO.exe is active, the script should convert it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe mlo.exe
shift & enter::Alt & n
Else
shift & enter
```

What is the correct AHK syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm). When using modified keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the symbols `+`, `^`, and `!` must be used.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe mlo.exe
    +Enter::!n
#If ; This closes the IfWinActive condition, only needed if more code is after
```